# How do I use a UITableView cell and its elements on prototype cell

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, interface-builder

I have started a new iPad project using this *Master-Detail* application. I am not a huge fan of creating stuff using Interface Builder, but for this project in particular I have to use that.

I need to create a custom cell to use on the `MasterViewController`. This cell will contain a switch and a label. Using interface builder, I have dragged these elements to what is called Prototype Cells inside what is called `TableView` Prototype Content.

This is what I get.

[image]

Now how do I use that inside `tableView:cellForRowIndexPath:`? Do I have to have outlets to use that `UILabel` and `UISwitch`? How do I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create `UITableViewCell` subclass and set it to your Prototype Cell in Storyboard.
Second Give your Prototype cell a reuse identifier in Storyboard.
Create `IBOutlet` of your `UILabel` and `UISwitch` in your newly created subclass of `UITableViewCell`
Import your custom cell class into your viewcontroller.m file 
In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method dequeue your custom cell

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *cellID = @"cell"; // identifier you have entered in storyboards
 CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

 if(!cell)
 {
  cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
 }

 //access your custom cell properties from now on
 cell.mySwith // or whatever name you gave it in your outlet

 return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should create a `UITableViewCell` subclass, and add `IBOutlets` for each control you'll need access to. Then, you set your subclass as the custom Class for each prototype cell in the identity inspector.

You'll also need to set the reuse identifier. Then, you can dequeue cells as you would normally do in `tableView:cellForRowIndexPath:`:

```
YourCustomCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: ahhhhh, thanks. Thats the part I was missing. This is why I never use IB.. 

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the cell a `Reuse Identifier` in Interface Builder after which you will be able to access the cell via:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Without subclassing you can give each element inside the cell a tag and use:

```
UISwitch *checkSwitch = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:-1];
```